# XML duplicate attribute android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Android Studio doesn't seem to detect any duplicates but I seem to keep getting this error when I try to build the application. I've looked through the code and removed duplicates I have spotted but the error still occurs. It works fine when I remove FloatingActionMenu.

```
D:\AndroidProjects\MeetUpProject\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:33: AAPT: error: duplicate attribute.
```

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/main_plans_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/main_plans_text"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_toolbar" />

<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
    android:id="@+id/main_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333333"
    app:menu_labels_colorPressed="#333333"
    app:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66EFECEC"
    app:menu_labels_textColor="#F2F1F1"
    fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="55"
    fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
    fab:menu_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
    fab:menu_colorPressed="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    fab:menu_colorRipple="#99d4d4d4"
    fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
    fab:menu_labels_cornerRadius="3dp"
    fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
    fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
    fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
    fab:menu_labels_position="left"
    fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
    fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
    fab:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
    fab:menu_labels_textColor="f2f1f1"
    fab:menu_labels_textSize="15dp"
    fab:menu_openDirection="up"
    fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
    fab:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
    fab:menu_shadowYOffset="4dp"
    fab:menu_showShadow="true">

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabContacts"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
        fab:fab_label="Contacts"
        fab:fab_size="mini" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabSettings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
        fab:fab_label="Settings"
        fab:fab_size="mini" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabLogout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app_black_24dp"
        fab:fab_label="Logout"
        fab:fab_size="mini" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabCreate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_create_black_24dp"
        fab:fab_label="Create"
        fab:fab_size="mini" />


</com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
```

Any answer would be greatly appreciated ~

Comment: Mind marking line 33 here in the code?

Comment: Seems weird, maybe it is because of  android:layout_margin="16dp". Try either defining only this line of marginEnd, marginBottom or the other two lines in com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu

Comment: @VarunRaj `<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu` is line 33 itself.

Comment: @SinanYaman I tried but I still get the same error message

Comment: Did you try to invalidate cache and restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `menu_labels_textColor` twice in the layout. Try to remove it like below:

```
<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
    android:id="@+id/main_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333333"
    app:menu_labels_colorPressed="#333333"
    app:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66EFECEC"
    app:menu_labels_textColor="#F2F1F1"
    fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="55"
    fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
    fab:menu_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
    fab:menu_colorPressed="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    fab:menu_colorRipple="#99d4d4d4"
    fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
    fab:menu_labels_cornerRadius="3dp"
    fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
    fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
    fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
    fab:menu_labels_position="left"
    fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
    fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
    fab:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
    fab:menu_labels_textSize="15dp"
    fab:menu_openDirection="up"
    fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
    fab:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
    fab:menu_shadowYOffset="4dp"
    fab:menu_showShadow="true">
```

Comment: I should really look at my code harder.

Thank you! Really appreciate it!!